# jquery / javascript ajax not working when loaded into page via jquery load()

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Have tried looking at answers similar but can't quite understand it.
I have tested the following code [www.mangocleaning.com/testing/pg1.php][1] and it works fine when used directly on its own page. However, when I load it via ajax load() to act as content within a current page it stops working. Can anyone help please? I copy and paste a lot and have limited understanding so please make it as simple for me to understand as you can please. Many thanks

```
 <script>

      function showEdit(editableObj){$(editableObj).css("background","#FFF");} 
      function saveToDatabase(editableObj,column,id) {
      $(editableObj).css("background","#CCC url(loaderIcon.gif) no-repeat right");
       $.ajax({
        url: "pg3.php",
        type: "POST",
        data:'column='+column+'&editval='+editableObj.innerHTML+'&id='+id,
        success: function(data){
    $(editableObj).css("background","#CCC");
    }        
});
}

</script>

</head>

<form name='userForm' id='userForm'>
<div><input type='text' name='company_name' placeholder='Company Name' /></div>
<div><input type='text' name='contact' placeholder='Contact' /></div>
<div><input type='text' name='priority' placeholder='Priority' /></div>
<div><input type='text' name='email_to' placeholder='Email to' /></div>
<div><input type='text' name='email_from' placeholder='Email from' /></div>
<div><input type='text' name='begin_message' placeholder='Dear / Hi / Hello' /></div>
<div><input type='text' name='message_text' placeholder='Message content' /></div>
<div><input type='text' name='end_message' placeholder='Many thanks / Kind regards' /></div>
<div><input type='submit' value='Submit' /></div>
</form>



<div class="table_outer">
<table class="table1" id="table1">

<thead>
    <th>id</th>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Person</th>
        <th>Email to</th>
        <th>Email from</th>
        <th>Begin message</th>
        <th>Text</th>
        <th>End message</th>
        <th>Delete</th>
</thead>

<?php
require_once("pg5.php");
$db_handle = new DBController();
$sql = "SELECT * from InvoiceEmailData";
$data = $db_handle->runQuery($sql);

foreach($data as $data_variable=>$dsdjgskjghkjfh) {
?>

<tr>
    <td contenteditable="false" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'id','<?php echo $data[$data_variable]["id"]; ?>')" onClick="showEdit(this);"><?php echo $data[$data_variable]["id"]; ?></td>
    <td contenteditable="true" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'Company','<?php echo $data[$data_variable]["id"]; ?>')" onClick="showEdit(this);"><?php echo $data[$data_variable]["Company"]; ?></td>
    <td contenteditable="true" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'Person','<?php echo $data[$data_variable]["id"]; ?>')" onClick="showEdit(this);"><?php echo $data[$data_variable]["Person"]; ?></td>
    <td contenteditable="true" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'EmailTo','<?php echo $data[$data_variable]["id"]; ?>')" onClick="showEdit(this);"><?php echo $data[$data_variable]["EmailTo"]; ?></td>
    <td contenteditable="true" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'EmailFrom','<?php echo $data[$data_variable]["id"]; ?>')" onClick="showEdit(this);"><?php echo $data[$data_variable]["EmailFrom"]; ?></td>
    <td contenteditable="true" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'BeginMessage','<?php echo $data[$data_variable]["id"]; ?>')" onClick="showEdit(this);"><?php echo $data[$data_variable]["BeginMessage"]; ?></td>
    <td contenteditable="true" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'Text','<?php echo $data[$data_variable]["id"]; ?>')" onClick="showEdit(this);"><?php echo $data[$data_variable]["Text"]; ?></td>
    <td contenteditable="true" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'EndMessage','<?php echo $data[$data_variable]["id"]; ?>')" onClick="showEdit(this);"><?php echo $data[$data_variable]["EndMessage"]; ?></td>

     <td> <input type="submit" id='<?php echo $data[$data_variable]["id"] ?>' value='Delete' class="delete-button"  /> </td>
</tr>

<?php
}
?>

</table>

JQUERY/AJAX TO SEND AND THEN RECEIVE BACK FORM DATA TO/FROM PG2  TO ADD TO TABLE ABOVE - ALSO DELETE ROWS USING DELETE QUERY FROM PG3
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js "></script>
<script>

delete_task(); // Call the delete_task function
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#userForm').submit(function(){

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'pg2.php', 
        data: $(this).serialize()
            })

    .done(function( data ) {$(data).appendTo('#table1').hide().fadeIn(2000);delete_task();
            })

    .fail(function() { alert( "Posting failed." ); });
        return false;

        });
    });

function delete_task() {
    $('.delete-button').click(function(){
    var current_element = $(this);
    var id = $(this).attr('id');

    $.post('pg4.php', { list_entry_id: id }, function() {
    current_element.parent().fadeOut(300, function() { $(this).closest('tr').remove(); });

});
    });

}
```

Comment: delete_task as to be in  $(document ready){ call else you can't exeute jquery in it cause it is not loaded ! and remove your return false in the submit it stop the function

Comment: sorry, the delete wasn't working and was going to look into that as it was working before. However, that wasn't the problem that I was referring to. None of the form or editable fields work from within the new page having been loaded via load()

Comment: missing space in name='userForm'id='userForm' ? :P

Comment: Thanks Froggiz, but that is not the problem. The page is all working fine (apart from the delete) when loaded directly into browser but stops working altogether apart from pulling data from database when loaded into another page via query load()

Comment: remove method from your form, edit your post with corrcted code so i could test it, and check your webbroser console error message + network ajax request status, it could help to help you. and try $('#userForm').submit(function(e){e.stopPropagation() ; to stop default page submit

Comment: 'method removed and space added'. Must be honest, don't understand the last bit of your post.?

Comment: the last part say : replace $('#userForm').submit(function(){ by $('#userForm').submit(function(e){e.stopPropagation() ;to prevent default navigation (submit to another page), i am going to check your code

Answer (score 0):

i added extra code at the end and it worked: 
you need to add e.preventDefault(); to prevent default browser submit
and  at the end of your sample code to have the javascript work

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js "></script>
     <script>

          function showEdit(editableObj){$(editableObj).css("background","#FFF");} 
          function saveToDatabase(editableObj,column,id) {
          $(editableObj).css("background","#CCC url(loaderIcon.gif) no-repeat right");
           $.ajax({
            url: "pg3.php",
            type: "POST",
            data:'column='+column+'&editval='+editableObj.innerHTML+'&id='+id,
            success: function(data){    $(editableObj).css("background","#CCC");
            }        
            });
            }

    </script>

    </head>

    <form name='userForm' id="userForm">
    <div><input type='text' name='company_name' placeholder='Company Name' /></div>
    <div><input type='text' name='contact' placeholder='Contact' /></div>
    <div><input type='text' name='priority' placeholder='Priority' /></div>
    <div><input type='text' name='email_to' placeholder='Email to' /></div>
    <div><input type='text' name='email_from' placeholder='Email from' /></div>
    <div><input type='text' name='begin_message' placeholder='Dear / Hi / Hello' /></div>
    <div><input type='text' name='message_text' placeholder='Message content' /></div>
    <div><input type='text' name='end_message' placeholder='Many thanks / Kind regards' /></div>
    <div><input type='submit' value='Submit' /></div>
    </form>



    <div class="table_outer">
    <table class="table1" id="table1">

    <thead>
        <th>id</th>
        <th>Company</th>
        <th>Person</th>
            <th>Email to</th>
            <th>Email from</th>
            <th>Begin message</th>
            <th>Text</th>
            <th>End message</th>
            <th>Delete</th>
    </thead>

    <?php
    require_once("pg5.php");
    $db_handle = new DBController();
    $sql = "SELECT * from InvoiceEmailData";
    $data = $db_handle->runQuery($sql);

    foreach($data as $data_variable=>$dsdjgskjghkjfh) {

    ?>

<tr>
    <td contenteditable="false" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'id','<?php echo $data[$data_variable]["id"]; ?>')" onClick="showEdit(this);"><?php echo $data[$data_variable]["id"]; ?></td>
    <td contenteditable="true" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'Company','<?php echo $data[$data_variable]["id"]; ?>')" onClick="showEdit(this);"><?php echo $data[$data_variable]["Company"]; ?></td>
    <td contenteditable="true" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'Person','<?php echo $data[$data_variable]["id"]; ?>')" onClick="showEdit(this);"><?php echo $data[$data_variable]["Person"]; ?></td>
    <td contenteditable="true" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'EmailTo','<?php echo $data[$data_variable]["id"]; ?>')" onClick="showEdit(this);"><?php echo $data[$data_variable]["EmailTo"]; ?></td>
    <td contenteditable="true" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'EmailFrom','<?php echo $data[$data_variable]["id"]; ?>')" onClick="showEdit(this);"><?php echo $data[$data_variable]["EmailFrom"]; ?></td>
    <td contenteditable="true" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'BeginMessage','<?php echo $data[$data_variable]["id"]; ?>')" onClick="showEdit(this);"><?php echo $data[$data_variable]["BeginMessage"]; ?></td>
    <td contenteditable="true" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'Text','<?php echo $data[$data_variable]["id"]; ?>')" onClick="showEdit(this);"><?php echo $data[$data_variable]["Text"]; ?></td>
    <td contenteditable="true" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'EndMessage','<?php echo $data[$data_variable]["id"]; ?>')" onClick="showEdit(this);"><?php echo $data[$data_variable]["EndMessage"]; ?></td>

     <td> <input type="submit" id='<?php echo $data[$data_variable]["id"] ?>' value='Delete' class="delete-button"  /> </td>
</tr>

    <?php
    }
    ?>

    </table>

    JQUERY/AJAX TO SEND AND THEN RECEIVE BACK FORM DATA TO/FROM PG2  TO ADD TO TABLE ABOVE - ALSO DELETE ROWS USING DELETE QUERY FROM PG3

    <script>

    //delete_task(); // Call the delete_task function
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#userForm').submit(function(e){

        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'pg2.php', 
            data: $(this).serialize()
                })

        .done(function( data ) {$(data).appendTo('#table1').hide().fadeIn(2000);delete_task();
                })

        .fail(function() { alert( "Posting failed." ); });
            return false;

            });



        });

    function delete_task() {
        $('.delete-button').click(function(){
        var current_element = $(this);
        var id = $(this).attr('id');

        $.post('pg4.php', { list_entry_id: id }, function() {
        current_element.parent().fadeOut(300, function() { $(this).closest('tr').remove(); });

    });
        });

    }
    </script>
    </html>
```

Comment: I am getting the alert box "posting failed" Also the editable fields do not work. Just to be clear in case I wasn't clear enough in the beginning... This all works fine when loaded normally by typing direct address into browser. However I am loading this as a sort of iframe using query load() function. this is where it stops working. It displays normally but the functions don't work. Thanks

Comment: that mean you don't have pg2.php at the same level of your page, so ajax can't reach it

Comment: I appreciate your time. Sorry to be a pain

Comment: by the way to know the error you can add this : fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {alert(textStatus);}

Comment: All the other pages are in the same folder as pg1. The error message just says 'error' Here is the page that it is not working on: http://www.mangocleaning.com/pre_release/index.php   -  goto to navpad 2 > invoices > setup.

Comment: pg2.php 404 not found, by the way you can add console.log(errorThrown); to have more infos in the browser log ! that mean pg2.php is not at the good place ! maybe you need to add a folder before or something like that in the page call, for info i saw the 404 not found error in brower network tab in developer tools

Comment: I tried moving the page to the root folder (public/html) but it still says posting failed. All of the required pages are also there now too. I've copied your code and tested in its own page but it doesn't work anymore. It did before :( I reverted the code back to original temporarily and it works again fine in its own page but still nothing on the dynamically loaded page.

Comment: error 404 mean page not found, so you have to find the way to have your ajax call at the same place than your php to be call directly

Comment: UPDATE: I managed to get the pages in the right place. The pages are communicating with each other now. Thanks. However !!!! the form data is not being sent to pg2. It submits, and a new row is added, but no form data? I have checked pg2 is working correctly by adding a set value for one of the variables and it does get added to the list when submit is pressed. Baaaaa! (btw the editing the table via ajax part of the page is working fine)

Comment: Got it working now. Thanks Froggiz for sticking with me. The answer above wasn't actually working but it certainly made be think of things a different way which ended up working.

Comment: i hope you undertoud where you can see logs to help debug this !